# Constant-time adding an element?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, polynomial-time, memory-allocation

Is a computer with infinite memory and infinite word size a Turing machine equivalent (in the sense that polynomial time remains polynomial time and exponential time remains exponential time) if we allow constant-time linked list element insertion (at the beginning of the list)?

I doubt this because element insertion requires memory allocation and allocation is usually not a constant-time operation.

Comment: http://www.gii.upv.es/tlsf/ claims constant-time memory allocation. But does that solution scale for systems of infinite memory (and infinite word size)?

Comment: A RAM computational model has no allocation cost. Infinite memory is there. You may assume zero-initialized memory. But initialization to another constant value should be assumed to take O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've found an $O(1)$ allocation strategy:

Because our memory is infinite, we may never deallocate: Just add memory at the end of the used space by incrementing a pointer.

Comment: How would you implement a process that generates elements and stores them systematically in an unbounded array, and stores randomly selected ones (with probability 1/2) in another unbounded array ?